# How to customize the behavior of the kube-scheduler on AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kube-scheduler

I'm trying to customize the behavior of the `kube-scheduler` on an AKS cluster (kubernetes v1.19.3), as described in [Scheduler Configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/).

My goal is to use the `NodeResourcesMostAllocated` plugin in order to schedule the pods using the least number of nodes possible.

Consider the following file - `most-allocated-scheduler.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
profiles:
  - schedulerName: default-scheduler
  - schedulerName: most-allocated-scheduler
    plugins:
      score:
        disabled:
        - name: NodeResourcesLeastAllocated
        enabled:
        - name: NodeResourcesMostAllocated
          weight: 2
```

According to the documentation, I can specify scheduling profiles by running something like:

```
kube-scheduler --config most-allocated-scheduler.yaml
```

But where exactly can I find the [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/) in order to run the above command? I'd like to do this ideally on a pipeline. Is it possible to do such thing when using AKS?

Answer (score 7):

[kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler) is a part of [kubernetes control plane](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#control-plane-components). It's components are scheduled on **master node**, to which on managed kubernetes solutions such as **AKS**, **GKE** or **EKS**, you have no access.

This means it's not possible to reconfigure your `kube-scheduler` on a running **AKS** cluster. Compare with [this](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/609#issuecomment-414100148) answer on **AKS's GitHub** page.

However, it is possible to provide custom configuration for your kube-scheduler when creating a new cluster, using [cluster definitions](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md), specifically in [schedulerConfig](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md#schedulerconfig) section:

> #### schedulerConfig
>
> `schedulerConfig`  declares runtime configuration for the
> kube-scheduler daemon running on all master nodes. Like
> `kubeletConfig`,  `controllerManagerConfig`, and  `apiServerConfig`
> it is a generic key/value object, and a child property of
> `kubernetesConfig`. An example custom apiserver config:
>
> ```
> "kubernetesConfig": {
>     "schedulerConfig": {
>         "--v": "2"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> See
> [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-scheduler/)
> for a reference of supported kube-scheduler options.
>
> ...

Keep in mind however that not all options are supported. Docs says that e.g. `--kubeconfig` is not supported, but as you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/), this flag is deprecated anyway. There is nothing about `--config` flag so you can simply try if it works.

You can also achieve it by using [Custom YAML for Kubernetes component manifests](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md#custom-yaml-for-kubernetes-component-manifests):

> Custom YAML specifications can be configured for kube-scheduler,
> kube-controller-manager, cloud-controller-manager and kube-apiserver
> in addition to the addons described
> [above](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md#addons).
> You will need to pass in a  *base64-encoded*  string of the kubernetes
> manifest YAML file to  *KubernetesComponentConfig["data"]*  . For
> example, to pass a custom kube-scheduler config, do the following:
>
> ```
> "kubernetesConfig": {
>     "schedulerConfig": {
>             "data" : "<base64-encoded string of your k8s manifest YAML>"
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> > ***NOTE***: Custom YAML for addons is an experimental feature. Since  `Addons.Data`  allows you to provide your own scripts, you are
> > responsible for any undesirable consequences of their errors or
> > failures. Use at your own risk.

So as you can see, even in managed kubernetes solutions such as **AKS**, `kube-scheduler` can be customized to certain extent, but only when you create a new cluster.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @mario, I would expect think kind of things to be at least a little bit easier. I'll try some of these things when I have some spare time.